# EL any function to get absolute value of a number?

Tags: jsp, jsf, jstl, el

I know the ugly way

```
a>0 ? a : -a
```

but this is very annoyng when a is a relatively long expression.

```
OBJ1["x"]-someVar>0 ? OBJ1["x"]-someVar : -(OBJ1["x"]-someVar)
```

Is there any nicer way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For plain jsp, you can create a custom EL function which delegates to [`Math#abs(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29).

If you first just create a `/WEB-INF/functions.tld` file which look like follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>Custom_Functions</short-name>
    <uri>http://example.com/functions</uri>

    <function>
        <name>abs</name>
        <function-class>java.lang.Math</function-class>
        <function-signature>int abs(int)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

Then you'll be able to use it as follows:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://example.com/functions" prefix="f" %>
...
${f:abs(OBJ1["x"]-someVar)}
```

This solution also works for JSF, but if you are using JSF, [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/) has simplified this for you by providing its [importFunctions](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importFunctions) (if not already using OmniFaces with JSF, you should start using it)

```
<o:importFunctions type="java.lang.Math" var="m" />
...
#{m:abs(-10)}
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: Shouldn't signature be float abs(float)?

Comment: If your input/output is `float`, yes. I however assumed it to be `int` based on educated guess. Note that EL functions have no notion of overloading. So if necessary, declare differently named `absInt()` and `absFloat()` functions.