# jsp expression language format negative numbers

Tags: jsp

I am using JSP expression language to format the numbers to currency like below

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US"/>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${list.lostTimeCost}"  type="currency"/>
```

I have both negative and positive numbers and want the negative numbers to be formated and shown as negative numbers but they are converted as number in parenthasis like ($5510) however I need it like -$5510 to show this is actually a loss the positive figures are the profit.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [absolute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749001/jsp-el-any-function-to-get-absolute-value-of-a-number).

Or, in the case of negative values, meaning you'd have to check if lostTimeCost < 0, you can convert them to positive by:

Using negation.

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${-list.lostTimeCost}"  type="currency"/>
```

Multiplying by -1.

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${list.lostTimeCost * -1}"  type="currency"/>
```