# Presentation/validation of negative zero in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, el

We have a jsp-page which presents some double values, on some of the doubles there is also a multiplication by -1 made on the jsp. This works fine except for zero values which is presented as "-0" and choose of correct css class fails in the el statement.

Here's an example to show the problem:

```
<c:set var="positiveZero" value="${0.0}" />
<c:set var="negativeZero" value="${0.0 * -1}" />

<p>negativeZero: ${negativeZero}</p>
<p>less than 0? ${negativeZero < 0}</p>

<p>positiveZero: ${positiveZero}</p>
<p>less than 0? ${positiveZero < 0}</p>
```

The output of this is:

```
negativeZero: -0.0
less than 0? true
positiveZero: 0.0
less than 0? false
```

Do you have any suggestion how to make sure the values are presented as "positive zeros" and also make sure that the "less than 0" statement returns false in both cases?

Comment: Try adding a zero to a negative zero. It should remove the minus sign.

Comment: I would look into this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749001/jsp-el-any-function-to-get-absolute-value-of-a-number

Comment: @Kaze, something similar to that could be a solution, but in this case I cannot use Math.ABS since in some occations the value is actually negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `0.00`.

Because:

> (-0.0) + 0.0 -> 0.0

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724031/how-can-a-primitive-float-value-be-0-0-what-does-that-mean/8153449#8153449) for the answer to a similar question and links to sources.

Comment: Thanks! The only drawback with this solution is that the JSP code will look a bit more "messy" since this will be added about 10 times on one single jsp. Is there no other more nice looking solution?

Comment: @SubUrban - Not sure how to make totally clean - may be worthwhile adding a static method in some Java library - something like `${MathLib.asPositive(negativeZero)}` perhaps.

Comment: The solution was to add an additional getValueInverted() method in my java model object which multiply by -1 and add 0.0d. With that method I can remove the calculation from jsp layer and also JUnit-test it, cleaner and nicer:-) Thanks for help!

Comment: @SubUrban - I would have called it `negate` but that is your call.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this little workaround:

```
${negativeZero < 0 ? -negativeZero : negativeZero}
```

Comment: This would not work in this particular case since some of the values actually are and should be presented as less than 0.