# Absolute value in outputText

Tags: java, jsf

Is it possible to get the absolute value of calculated values in jsf? 1 column of the dataTable (myDt) has the calculated days between 2 dates but it must be the absolute value of it.

```
<p:column headerText="Days">
<h:outputText value="#{(myDt.receptionDate.getTime()-
myBean.currentdate.getTime())/(24*60*60*1000)}"/>
</p:column>
```

Thx.

Comment: Reverse the two dates? Or if you need both, use a ternary expression...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSP/EL any function to get absolute value of a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749001/jsp-el-any-function-to-get-absolute-value-of-a-number)

Comment: Doing https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&q=EL+function+absolute+java  resulted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749001/jsp-el-any-function-to-get-absolute-value-of-a-number (knowing it is EL and not 'focussing' on an outputText helps in getting better results from google).